# how to use a bitmap taken by the camera through multiple activities in android?

Tags: android, image, android-intent, android-activity, bitmap

I am making a photo app in which in the first activity the user takes a picture (he can see the picture in the ImageView), in the second activity he chooses with who to share the image,and in the 3rd activity he should be able to see the image again in a different ImageView than the first to add some data. I know how to move the bitmap from one activity to the next one by an intent, but how to do it if i want to send it to the 3rd activity of my user path? If i startActivity(intent) it will skip my second activity and if i don´t put it the 3rd activity is showing me an empty ImageView.. Can someone please help me in telling me ways of how to automatically load (without user interaction) this picture in the 1st and 3rd activity and some example?

I already being reading posts about how to convert to Base64 and load again, but their examples are using images already in the memory of the phone and in my case are pictures that were just taken by the user, so in principle i don´t know the name of the image file..

Thank a lot!

Comment: is this true? first activity starts second activity and then second activity starts the 3rd one. 
is this your scenario?

Comment: Yes, the first one, creates an intent for the camera, the user takes a picture and this gets returned into a ImageView, the second is a Share window activity and then the user goes to the 3rd that is a ImageView where he must see the picture he took again. Do not know how to pass the image to the 3rd activity..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Add This Image In Your Custome Catch Folder**

Like Make Your Folder in External or Internal Storage

Then Save Image that will capture by camera inside That Folder..

```
public static void SaveImagecatch(Bitmap finalBitmap) throws IOException {

    File Folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/data/Catch");
    if (Folder.mkdir()) {
        nomediaFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/data/Catch/" + NOMEDIA);
        if (!nomediaFile.exists()) {
            nomediaFile.createNewFile();
        }
    }
    String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
    File myDir = new File(root + "/data/Catch");
    myDir.mkdirs();
    Random generator = new Random();
    int n = 10000;
    n = generator.nextInt(n);
    String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
    File file = new File(myDir, fname);
    Catch_uri = Uri.parse("file://" + myDir + "/" + fname);
    if (file.exists()) file.delete();
    try {
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
        finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, out);
        out.flush();
        out.close();
        Log.e("yes", "yes");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("no", "no");
    }
}
```

Then.. get Image From Uri path of Your saved Image.

```
Uri imageUri = Catch_uri; 
Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(),imageUri);
Imageview my_img_view = (Imageview ) findViewById (R.id.my_img_view);
my_img_view.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
```

This is Worked For Me.. I Hope This Will be Helpfull to you

Answer (score 0):

Actually in second activity, you need to get Intent from first activity and do your work and then create new Intent and put your image into it, finally start third activity using new intent.

in second activity:

```
Intent firstToSecodeIntent = getIntent();
// some codes
Intent secondToThirdIntent = new Intent(this, ThirdActivity.class);
Intent.putExtra("image", /*your Image object*/);
startActivity(secondToThirdIntent);
```

in third activity:

```
Intent secondToThirdIntent = getIntent();
// get your image and set it into your imageView
```

Comment: make a static bitmap field in third activity and from ur current activity you can fill the third activity bitmap , check bitmap not equal to null in third activity ,then set it on the third sctivity